# HttpMessageDecoder will call the next handler, when the header length is over the frame size

Tags: httprequest, netty

I create the simple http-server with netty and test it.
HTTP client send an illegal http request to the server.
The illegal http request has too long header(over 8192bytes).

But when HttpMessageDecoder received the last frame of the tcp stream, it called the next handler with the partial request.
The request is concatenate the first and the last frame.

I think, it should be called the reset() method, when HttpMessageDecoder throws TooLongFrameException.

I created the code to reproduce this issue.
(I changed 2 classes of HttpHelloWorldServer in netty-example)

HttpHelloWorldServerPipelineFactory.java

```
public class HttpHelloWorldServerPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    // Create a default pipeline implementation.
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();

    // Uncomment the following line if you want HTTPS
    //SSLEngine engine = SecureChatSslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
    //engine.setUseClientMode(false);
    //pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));

    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    // Uncomment the following line if you don't want to handle HttpChunks.
    //pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    // Remove the following line if you don't want automatic content compression.
    //pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpHelloWorldServerHandler());
    return pipeline;
}
}
```

HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java

```
public class HttpHelloWorldServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

private static final byte[] CONTENT = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' };

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    Object msg = e.getMessage();
    Channel ch = e.getChannel();
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) msg;

        System.out.println("messageReceived:[req=" + req + "]");

        if (is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
            Channels.write(ctx, Channels.future(ch), new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, CONTINUE));
        }

        boolean keepAlive = isKeepAlive(req);
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
        response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT));
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.getContent().readableBytes());

        if (!keepAlive) {
            ChannelFuture f = Channels.future(ch);
            f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
            Channels.write(ctx, f, response);
        } else {
            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
            Channels.write(ctx, Channels.future(ch), response);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    Channel ch = e.getChannel();
    if(cause instanceof TooLongFrameException) {
        ChannelFuture f = ch.write(new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, BAD_REQUEST));
        f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    } else {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
}
}
```

and start the HttpHelloWorldServer and send the request with the long header(about 8200bytes).

This server output to stdout as below.

```
$ java -cp . org.jboss.netty.example.http.helloworld.HttpHelloWorldServer
messageReceived:[req=DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
GET / HTTP/1.1
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest:
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.3 (java 1.5)]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuff
er(AbstractNioWorker.java:433)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCod
e(AbstractNioWorker.java:128)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handle
AcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventS
unk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOn
eEncoder.java:71)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream
(OneToOneEncoder.java:59)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:686)
        at org.jboss.netty.example.http.helloworld.HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.m
essageReceived(HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java:72)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:29
6)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessage
Received(FrameDecoder.java:459)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(Repl
ayingDecoder.java:536)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(Replayi
ngDecoder.java:554)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(
FrameDecoder.java:365)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.jav
a:396)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNi
oWorker.java:360)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handle
AcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventS
unk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream
(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:19
7)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener$1.operationComplete(Cha
nnelFutureListener.java:41)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultCh
annelFuture.java:427)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChann
elFuture.java:145)
        at org.jboss.netty.example.http.helloworld.HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.e
xceptionCaught(HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java:85)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(Fram
eDecoder.java:377)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:52
5)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractC
hannelSink.java:48)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:26
8)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:25
5)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(Abstract
NioWorker.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNi
oSelector.java:318)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioW
orker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Best regards.

Comment: I attached the code to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Please open a bug report via our bug tracker[1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I created the issue.[https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2009](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2009)